# Change Master Detail Relationship default behavior

Tags: relationships, master-detail

There is a 'Communities' object in Salesforce that has a master-detail object called 'Baseline Surveys' below it (For every community, there can be several baseline surveys). However, a city lead contacts you and gives you the number of a baseline survey, and says that he does not want this belonging to Community B, but Community A, and that when he wants to change this, he receives an error saying that it is not possible to change. What setting do you need to check in order to make sure that the city lead can be allowed to do this successfully?

Comment: Hi roshni, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check this checkbox **`Child records can be reparented to other parent records after they are created`** (labelled as *Allow Reparenting*)on the field so that their parent can be changed (For Example, from Community A to Community B).

Steps to achieve this:

1. Go to the detail page of the "Baseline Survey" object and find the master-detail relationship field.
2. Edit this field and select the above mentioned checkbox.
3. Save the changes, now you should be able to change the master (Community) of the detail (Baseline Survey) records.